# when create Order and Customer via API Shopify data not show in Admin panel

Tags: shopify

I have a problem with Shopify API. I use python API for Shopify. When I create a new order via API, data exists (I check via API too) but it's not shown within Shopify admin panel.

Comment: What did you try? Do you get a 200 ok when POSTing to either create a cuatomer or an order? Can you share the data which you want to insert using the API?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty likely that you're interacting with two different stores if you're getting 200 OKs and seeing the Orders come back through the API and not through the admin.

It's worth checking `shopify.Shop.current().domain` to see if it matches up with the admin that you're interacting with. If you're still seeing issues, post the contents of your request (including headers) and it will be a lot easier to give you a hand :)